# Preventing too many Register requests

Tags: java, php, android

I understand that I have no code to show or that I have problem with.

I have an Android application which lets users register by email, username and password.These values will be sent to a server which will query them into the registeration database. However, it will be possible for anyone to keep sending requests including those needed parameters to the server and register new fake users. Is there any way to block these type of fake requests?

Creating special keys inside the application and sending it to the server for identification will still make it able for hackers to identify and capture that specific key and therefore put it into their requests for creating fake accounts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within your app, you can always record the time you sent a registration request in a shared preference and the next time they click your button check and see if enough time has passed.

That will protect you from doing it within your app.  That won't work to block them from doing it from your API.  That would require rate throttling, which is too large a topic to discuss here, but some googling on that term will help you.